# Battlefield 4 White Screen of Death

Tags: technical-issues, battlefield-4, battlelog

After a recent update Battlefield 4, anytime I try to join a server I get an error in my Battlelog which isn't very helpful. . . "ERROR: Game Disconnected, something went wrong." and during the loading if I open my BF4 game window, it's completely white.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall, I've tried to repair I'm not sure what my other options are. What can I do to get my BF4 to start working again?

I'm running Windows 8 - 64bit and I've run it just fine before so I'm pretty sure the update broke it.

Comment: Updated your video card drivers?

Comment: I tried that and still the same result. I think I'm being punished for uninstalled the Hardline Beta :/